# How can I register a Client through an express REST API in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: rest, express, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I want to register a user of the application through a REST API. I have already enrolled the admin and a user through the [enrollAdmin.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/javascript/enrollAdmin.js) and [registerUser.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/javascript/registerUser.js) function but I want to call these functions through the node SDK and register users **dynamically** with there username (UUID) so that it's completly anonymous.
As the username I want to create a unique UUID and save that in the world state but also save that UUID on an off-chain database together with the personal information like password and name so that I can associate the personal information with the UUID.
Right know I'm confused by all the different steps  I have to do to register a new user:
In what order do I have to enroll and register the user and should they all be defined in the express API or in chaincode?

This is my first approach of creating the REST Api and till now I have only defined the layout, the connection profile and wallet.
I would appreciate if somebody  could help me implement the registration process in the express REST API so that an Identity for the UUID gets saved in the world state.
Thanks in advance.

- server.js

```js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

// Setting for Hyperledger Fabric
const { Wallets, FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const channelName = 'mychannel';
const mspOrg1 = 'Org1MSP';
const walletPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'wallet');
const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'connection-org1.json');

//register
app.post('/api/register', async function (req, res) {
    try{

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

    } catch (error)  {

    }
});

//login
app.post('/api/login', async function (req, res) {
    try{

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
        
    } catch (error)  {

    }
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("***********************************");
    console.log("API server listening at localhost:3000");
    console.log("***********************************");
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of how you want it to be is simple. In the middle, the off-chain database is used as a mapping table. I wrote only the core process logic.

#### /api/v1/register

0. validation check
   Validate that the user's id is unique, that the required information value is missing, that the regular expression is correct, and that there is no wrong information.
1. generate random UUID
   Create a random, unique uuid first. [`npm/uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

```js
const UUID = uuid.v4();
```

2. register/enroll user to fabric-ca
   Perform the registration process as a user of the fabric. The information that goes into this process is UUID, and the user's information will not be stored in the blockchain.
   `fabricUser` is a newly created class, and returns the result after fabric user registration and enroll process are performed by the Enroll method.

```js
enrollment = await fabricUser.Enroll(UUID);
await wallet.put(enrollment);
```

3. insert to database
   While saving the user information in the database, map it by storing the UUID created above.
   The database was created as an example, assuming [`mongodb`](https://mongodb.com/).

```js
db.collection('User').insertOne({
    'uuid': UUID,
    'user_id': <input_user_id>,
    ...
});
```

#### /api/v1/login

The login process is as follows.
I don't know what authentication/authentication method you want to use, so I'll assume a token authentication method based on auth 2.0.

0. Verify the validity of the necessary information required for login and whether there is any incorrect information.
1. get UUID
   `generateAuthToken` is a new function that generates [`JWT`](https://jwt.io/).

```js
let res = await db.collection("User").findOne({'user_id': `<input_user_id>` });
return generateAuthToken(res.uuid);
```

#### /api/v1/invoke

Fabric resource request process is as follows.

0. Token validation and resource authorization check
1. get `userName` from `token`
   `getPayload` is a function that gets the payload value located at the 1st index from the token.

```js
const rawPayload = getPayload(token);
const jsonPayload = JSON.parse(rawPayload);
return jsonPayload
```

2. get wallet & invoke chaincode
   The `fabricChaincode` is a function that wraps the invoke process of fabric-sdk. It is a function that executes invoke by inputting identity, chaincode information, and parameters, and returns a result.

```js
const user = await db.collection("User").findOne({'user_id': jsonPayload.user_id });
const fabricIdentity = await wallet.get(user.uuid);
const res = fabricChaincode.invoke(fabricIdentity, `<your_chaincode_info>`, `<input_chaincode_params>`)
return res;
```

---

[EDIT]

Add it for your understanding.

fabricUser.js

```js
/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function Enroll(user_id) {
    try {
        // load the network configuration
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
        const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));

        // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
        const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities['ca.org1.example.com'].url;
        const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userIdentity = await wallet.get(user_id);
        if (userIdentity) {
            console.log(`An identity for the user ${user_id} already exists in the wallet`);
            return;
        }

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
        const adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin');
        if (!adminIdentity) {
            console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the enrollAdmin.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // build a user object for authenticating with the CA
        const provider = wallet.getProviderRegistry().getProvider(adminIdentity.type);
        const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');

        // Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
        const secret = await ca.register({
            affiliation: 'org1.department1',
            enrollmentID: user_id,
            role: 'client'
        }, adminUser);
        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
            enrollmentID: user_id,
            enrollmentSecret: secret
        });
        const x509Identity = {
            credentials: {
                certificate: enrollment.certificate,
                privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
            },
            mspId: 'Org1MSP',
            type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put(user_id, x509Identity);
        console.log(`Successfully registered and enrolled admin user ${user_id} and imported it into the wallet`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to register user ${user_id}: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Enroll
}
```

api.js

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
const fabricUser = require('./fabricUser);
const UUID = uuid.v4();
let res = await fabricUser.Enroll(UUID);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But to register/enroll the user to the fabric-ca do I only have to use your two lines of code because in the [fabcar samples)(https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/javascript/registerUser.js) they do way more steps like defining the provider and then call ca.register and ca.enroll.

Comment: As written in the answer, `Enroll` is a new function.
The easiest way to implement it is to export the function of the [registerUesr](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/javascript/registerUser.js) code you suggested above. In addition, all you need to do is to pass internally necessary arguments as function parameters and return the operation result. The internal function of registerUser looks complicated, but it is a part that simply configures configurations, and it can be executed sufficiently in an event-driven form without significant cost.

Comment: I've added an additional answer to make it easier for you to understand. Refer to it with very easy code.

Comment: All right that's amazing thanks for your efforts. Would you recommend just using the docs for the node SDK to develop the application backend or do you know about some more docs?

Comment: In fact, in my case, the fabric-sdk-node document is used only for checking the existence of classes and methods and input/output. I think that related documents are insufficient, and when developing, it is unavoidable to directly analyze the fabric-sdk-node code itself and interpret it and use it. That part doesn't help you much :(.

Comment: I'm creating a REST API for the HLF too. Using `mongoose` (for MongoDB), I created an user model that saves the organization it relates to and the role ("admin" for CA operations and "client" for smart contract operations), and another model for saving the organization name with the the `ccp`. But I have this doubt: Should I use `FileSystemWallet` to save the blockchain network users or should I store them elsewhere?